# Open Jar through batch file through PATH

Tags: java, batch-file, jar, cmd, path

I made a batch file that executes commands through a jar:

```
@java -jar commands.jar %*
```

This is the file tree:

```
C:\
     Commands\
              commands.bat
              commands.jar
```

I have my PATH variable set to "C:\Commands\" so that I can access the commands from anywhere on the PC. I can successfully run the batch file, but for some reason it won't open the jar. When I type

> commands

or

> commands help

it says

> Error: unable to access jarfile commands.jar

I have tried using quotes around the jar name, I have tried moving the jar... nothing works...

Comment: What directory are you running the command in?

Comment: You overwrote the PATH variable, which now no longer contains the path to java.exe!

Comment: @SomethingDark Thanks, but no. I added C:\Commands to path, I didn't overwrite it completely. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%~dp0` gives bat file path so

```
@java -jar %~dp0commands.jar %*
```

See `call /?` for help (even though we aren't using `call`).

By using `ftype`, `assoc`, and editing with `setx` the variable `pathext` to add `jar` files you can just type the jar's name and have it run without a batch file needed.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed! Thanks! I should've thought of this, it's simple logic. If I'm running the batch in let's say... "C:\Users\Admin\Dekstop" when the .jar is still in the commands folder, it wouldn't work.